# Sublime Text is unable to run Python code

Tags: python, debugging, sublimetext

Im new to programming and I need a project for my computer science class. Im using Sublime Text with python, but it will not run any code on my personal computer. I did some test stuff on the school desktops and I had no problems with anything.

Here is the error it is giving. I censored my name.

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['py', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\_____\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\PYTHON\\Final\\final']]
[dir: C:\Users\_____\OneDrive\Desktop\PYTHON\Final]
[path: C:\Program Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Users\_____\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;]
[Finished]
```

[image: The Sample Code]

I've tried changing file locations, turning it off and on again, making a new file, reinstalling, and using a new device. Only using a new device worked. Everything gives the same error

Comment: None of the locations in your `PATH` look like they would contain a Python installation; have you installed Python on this computer? In particular, if you happen to be trying to use the version of Python you can get from the windows store, it does not include the `py` helper that Sublime is trying to execute when you use the default `Python.sublime-build` build system.